# collapseActionView() deprecated

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, deprecated

I'm trying to close an action bar search view programmatically.  Using the code

```
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(action_search);
```

worked fine, but collapseActionView showed as deprecated.  The documentation states.

> This method was deprecated in API level 26.1.0. Use
>   collapseActionView() directly.

so, I changed my code to

```
collapseActionView(action_search);
```

which also works fine, and also shows as deprecated.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing that the static method `MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(MenuItem)` is deprecated. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#collapseActionView(android.view.MenuItem)) says that you should use the instance method `MenuItem.collapseActionView()` instead.

However, you say:

> so, I changed my code to
>
> ```
> collapseActionView(action_search);
> ```

This doesn't really make sense. What object are you calling `collapseActionView(MenuItem)` on? `Activity` and `Fragment` don't have any such methods. Additionally, you're still passing a `MenuItem` argument to the method; the suggested replacement has no arguments at all.

I suspect that what you've done is statically imported the `MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(MenuItem)` method. Check your imports for this item:

```
import static android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView;
```

To fix it, delete the line you have now and replace it with:

```
action_search.collapseActionView();
```

Note that [the documentation for `MenuItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#collapseActionView()) says nothing about `collapseActionView()` being deprecated.

Comment: Exactly correct on all points.  Thank you for the quick, detailed, well explained answer.